# mouseover property for asp:Image tag dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

i have an asp:Image tag

```
  <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgDeptHeader" />
```

and i set its imageurl as

```
 ImgDeptHeader.ImageUrl = imgpath + txtCatimage;
```

i need to show large image onmouseover dynamically.how can i set it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

i have done it using jquery and html image

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
                function ImageAssign() {
        //set source of html img
                    document.getElementById("image1").src = document.getElementById("<%= Hidden_Resource.ClientID %>").value;

                }
            </script>

            <script type="text/javascript">

            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

              //  var ss = 'small.jpg';
                $('#image1').addimagezoom({
                    zoomrange: [3, 10],
                    magnifiersize: [300, 300],
                    magnifierpos: 'right',
                    cursorshade: true,

                })
            })

            </script>
image tag:

<img id="image1" border="0" src="" alt="img" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an onMouseOver attribute to any control that renders to the page.

```
    private void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    imgButton.Attributes.Item("onMouseOver") = "javascript:swapImageIn('myID');return true;"
     imgButton.Attributes.Item("onMouseOut") = "javascript:swapImageOut(); return true;" 
    }
```

Comment: sorry its .Attributes.Add("onMouseOver","javascript:swapImageIn('myID');return true;");